# live textarea Highlighter problem

Tags: javascript

i using SyntaxHighlighter and i have an text area

```
<textarea id="content" onchange="perview();"></textarea>
```

and

```
function perview() {
var code = $("textarea#content").val();
$('#code-preview').html(code);
}
```

and

```
<pre id="code-preview" class="brush: php;"></pre>
```

and i started the highlightrt

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

but when typing there is no any change happing
just there is an Highlighter has no text

Comment: @moustafa please see my answer as i have changed it to a working version.

Answer (score 0):

This does work on my system.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').keyup(function() {
            var code = $('#content').val();
            $('#code-preview').html(code);
        });
    });

</script>

<textarea cols="10" id="content"></textarea>
<pre id="code-preview"></pre>
```